# What does commute/commutation mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, translation, legalese

I am trying to understand the following sentence from a legal document. Can anyone explain me what 'commutation' means?

> Immovable property presently sold is free and clear of all seigniorial
>   dues having commuted and the price of commutation has been paid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Commute](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/commute) definition 4: "to pay (an annuity) at one time, esp. with a discount".

In other words, the taxpayer has made an agreement to pay one large instalment, and in return be free of all seigniorial dues in the future. Such agreements are not uncommon; many modern travellers *commute* their daily fares into one large annual fee, and are called *commuters*.